# Python, sort a list of lists by date object

Tags: python, list, sorting, datetime

I have a list of lists that is of the following form:

```
[ [date_objects], [int], [int], [int], [int] ]
```

All the lists are the same length, and I would like to sort all of the lists by the date_objects list. I can change the format of the data if needed, but I need all of the changes in index numbers that occurs in date_objects to occur in each subsequent list..

Thanks

Comment: so you want the dates sorted first? Can you add some actual input and expected output as it is not totally clear what you are asking

Comment: Please, explain better this part: "I would like to sort all of the lists by the date_objects list"

Comment: Your question would seem much better if it contained what you tried before making the question here on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to create a list of lists in the "other" order:

```
[
[date_obj, int, int, int, int],
[date_obj, int, int, int, int],
[date_obj, int, int, int, int]
...
]
```

You can do this with either a loop or a list comprehension.
Now, sort the list you just created.
Finally, reverse the process to get your original 5 lists, but now sorted into the desired order.

Consider whether you want to do this last step at all.  It might be easier to index this as a row-ordered table.

Does that get you moving?